# How to read local file with Grails?

Tags: grails, file-io, groovy

When my Grails application starts, I build up a data structure from a CSV file downloaded from a remote URL. If the file is not accessible, I'd like to fall back to a local copy. Currently processing the file in the service layer, initiated using a Quartz job.

**What is the best practice, using Groovy, for reading a local resource in Grails?**

- Where should I stash the file?
- How do I safely and properly read the file?

*General-case answers will be very acceptable.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to deal with this is to store the file's location in an [externalized configuration file](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration).

So, you'd determine a standardized location (such as `/etc/myappname/CSVFileConfig.groovy`), or pass the config file path in using an environment variable or something similar.  See [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration) for examples.

Then you can simply add the actual path to the local file to that extenal config, like so:

```
// CSVFileConfig.groovy
my.custom.csv.path = ...
```

Finally, access it using normal config operations:

```
// in your Quartz job
def path = grailsApplication.config.my?.custom?.csv?.path
if(!path) {
    // no file to load
} else {
    // load file
}
```

As far as reading the file, what are your primary concerns?  If you are using a CSV library, such as OpenCSV (used in [most of the Grails libraries for CSV parsing](http://www.grails.org/plugin/csv)), it will handle the opening and parsing of the file.

For security issues beyond that, I'm not sure how to handle them in a generic way.  It will depend on your specific scenario.  I think the one coming from a URL has a higher risk factor.

Comment: Well, you still aren't providing much to go on for answering *"how to safely and properly read the file"*, but you can read the file using `new File(path).withReader{ reader -> ... }`, which handles opening and closing the file.

Comment: Sorry if specifics are lacking here. Generally uncomfortable having solutions coded up for me. New to Grails/Groovy but im an avid coder so looking for reasons to choose one strategy over another. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I highly recommend both the Groovy in Action and Grails in Action books.  They'll help get you going.  Groovy is more than just syntactic changes to Java.  The `withWriter` method is part of the Groovy-JDK extensions to Java.