# Adding a file in bootstrap.groovy in grails 3?

Tags: grails

I would like to add a file in the bootstrap.groovy file in grails 3.3.9 version. 
In the bootstrap.groovy:

```
package com.nuevaconsulting
import com.nuevaconsulting.embrow.*

class BootStrap {
def init = { servletContext ->

        def filePath = "C:/Grails/embrow/grails-app/conf/resourcesresources/1.csv"
        new File(filePath).splitEachLine(',') 
        {
        fields ->
def employee = new Employee(
    mirId: fields[0].trim(),
   cancer : fields[1].trim(),
    profile : fields[1].trim(),
     pubmed : fields[1].trim()      
)

if ( employee.hasErrors() ||  employee.save(flush: true) == null) {
    log.error("Could not import  employee  ${ employee.errors}")
}

log.debug("Importing  employee  ${ employee.toString()}")
}
def destroy = {}}}
```

When I execute run-app, I ended-up with the following error

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

    Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
Error Failed to start server (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip'.
 Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    ... 78 more
| Error Failed to start server
```

How can I add and visualize ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/8622990/615274

Comment: Are you sure your `resourcesresources` is correct?

Comment: @Mamun yeah. Thats my folder name

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace, otherwise hard to guess

Comment: @MamunSardar Ive edited my post with stacktrace. kindly check